# Trying to break apart a long line from a JSON response

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working within Python 3.6.3 and am connecting to an MDM solution via REST API and the result of my query is coming back as:

```
[{'SampleTime': '4/17/2018 6:39:00 PM', 'Latitude': '32.18007400', 'Longitude': '-94.35314700', 'Elevation': '72.76', 'Speed': '16.43', 'DeviceId': {'Value': 74365}, 'Id': {'Value': 126709703}}, {'SampleTime': '4/17/2018 6:24:00 PM', 'Latitude': '32.18735200', 'Longitude': '-94.36022700', 'Elevation': '64.67', 'Speed': '5.59', 'DeviceId': {'Value': 74365}, 'Id': {'Value': 126705738}},...]
```

But when I try and manipulate this long line into indiviudual records I keep hitting problems such as each line in my output file is the same and includes all records from the json output - so not what I am wanting, I want each record to be on it's own row, vs what is happening each row has all records :(

As can be seen in the code below, I am using straightforward calls, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
awTest = requests.get(consoleURL + "/api/mdm/devices/gps?searchby=Serialnumber&id=" + deviceSerial + "&dayrange=" + lookupDays, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + b64EncodedAuth, "aw-tenant-code": tenantCode,"Accept": "application/json;version=1"}, timeout=30)
deviceDetails = awTest.json()

for SampleTime in deviceDetails:
    #print(deviceDetails)
    logging.info(deviceDetails)
```

Comment: Do you mean to `logging.info(SampleTime)`?

Comment: What problems? can you provide the errors?

Comment: Please pull the `print(deviceDetails)` outside the for loop and post the printed result here

Comment: logging.info: what I am using to write to my file for testing

Comment: logging.info: what I am using to write to my file for testing; Problems: That's the thing, instead of having 57 rows representing 57 different SampleTime entries, but instead I get 57 rows, with each row has the a string of the 57 entries instead of just 1. Which is what I want :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

awTest.json returns you with a list of dicts:

```
[{'SampleTime': '4/17/2018 6:39:00 PM', 'Latitude': '32.18007400', 'Longitude': '-94.35314700', 'Elevation': '72.76', 'Speed': '16.43', 'DeviceId': {'Value': 74365}, 'Id': {'Value': 126709703}}, {'SampleTime': '4/17/2018 6:24:00 PM', 'Latitude': '32.18735200', 'Longitude': '-94.36022700', 'Elevation': '64.67', 'Speed': '5.59', 'DeviceId': {'Value': 74365}, 'Id': {'Value': 126705738}},...]
```

You can iterate it the following way:

```
for item in deviceDetails:
    logging.info(item)
```

Or if you need only SampleTime from each record:

```
for item in deviceDetails:
    logging.info(item['SampleTime'])
```

Comment: Yes.  I used this code:  jsonData = awTest.json
 jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)  and get the following error:     jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'method'

Comment: It should be: jsonData = awTest.json(). You forgot to put parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, its been one of those days, added the () and now get: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'

Comment: It looks like request already giving you a python dict inside a list. So there's no need to use json.loads. I will update the answer

Comment: THANK YOU! That has been my issue all along, appreciate your patience.